# filtro customizado com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fala pessoal, estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma lista de nomes:

```
$scope.names=["Max", "Tom", "Ralf", "Jerry", "Snow", "Carl"];
```

Fiz um filter normal para o input search

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter: search">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<input type="search" ng-model="search">
</div>
```

No entanto eu quero criar um custom filter para mostrar apenas os nomes relacionados a 1º letra digitada no input search, no caso, digitar a letra "R" e o resultado seja apenas "Ralf" invés de buscar o "R" em todas as letras, que resulta em "Ralf" e "Jerry".

Pensei em usar um angular.forEach para percorrer os nomes mas não consegui o resultado que queria, caso ajude, segue o codepen para facilitar:

http://codepen.io/haykou/pen/aDczA

Comment: Por favor, poste o código do seu filtro até o momento, e qual o resultado esta obtendo com ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, achei uma solução como eu queria, só não entendi a parte do regex.test mas acho que a solução pode servir para outras pessoas com dúvida.

```
var List = function($scope){
 $scope.names=["Tax", "Tom", "Ralf", "Jerry", "Snow", "Carl"];

  function escRegExp(string){
   return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g);
    }

  $scope.filterSearch = function(name) {
 if (!$scope.search){
   return true;
 }else
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + escRegExp($scope.search), 'i');
    return regex.test(name.split(' ')[0]);
};  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode  criar um filtro personalizado e registrá-lo no angular.

#### 1 - Criar um modulo

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
<html ng-app="app">
```

#### 2 - Registrar o controller neste modulo

```
app.controller('List',List)
```

#### 3 - Criar o filter

```
app.filter('firstType',function(){
  return function(input, type){
    var results = [];
    for(var i in input){
      var name = input[i];
        if(name[0]==type)
            results.push(name);
    }
    return results;
  };
});
```

#### 4 - Chamar o filter

```
<div ng-controller="List">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names | firstType: filterSearch">{{name}}</li>
  </ul> 
  <div>
    <input type="search" ng-model="filterSearch">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Alguns links para auxilo:

- **[Seu código funcionando aqui](http://jsbin.com/qipati/1/edit)**
- **[Everything about custom filters in AngularJS](http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/)**